# How does Laravel convert the associative array into variables when passing data to views

Tags: php, laravel

When you pass an associate array of data to views with Laravel, how does that associative array get converted into variables? I tried to look at the source code but I can't quite see how it's done.

```
// View
view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria', 'title' => 'Test']);

// Using the associative array data in the templates
<?php echo $name; ?>
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views

Is PHP's extract function used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it uses the `extract` function.

You can find this in the source code here [Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php#L37).

Answer (score 0):

After passing data to view you can display the above data as follow.

```
//this one will display the name

   {{$greetings['name']}}

//this one will display the title

  {{$greetings['title']}}
```